# ts() function not define

Tags: drupal, upgrade

This issue is related to ts() which is used in JS files and it's not working. The problem is that the system returns an error every time it encounters ts() saying that it is not a function.

I have updated CiviCRM to the latest version (4.7.12) for Drupal 7, and also updated Drupal to the latest version (7.51) of D7 and updated all required modules for Drupal and extensions for CiviCRM. But the CiviCRM Dashboard is not displaying any content or error. When I review the browser console I found following error:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$injector/modulerr?p0=crmApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.20%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DcrmMailing%26p1%3Dts%2520is%2520not%2520a%2520function%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fcivicrm%252Fajax%252Fangular-modules%253Fformat%253Djs%2526r%253DZZ1eW%253A2248%253A29%250Ar%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fofjxxt%253A7%253A426%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fcivicrm%252Fajax%252Fangular-modules%253Fformat%253Djs%2526r%253DZZ1eW%253A2243%253A7%250Ae%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fofjxxt%253A36%253A313%250Ad%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fofjxxt%253A34%253A490%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fofjxxt%253A35%253A117%250Ar%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fofjxxt%253A7%253A320%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fofjxxt%253A34%253A399%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fofjxxt%253A35%253A63%250Ar%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fofjxxt%253A7%253A320%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fofjxxt%253A34%253A399%250Acb%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fofjxxt%253A38%253A135%250Atc%252Fd%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fofjxxt%253A17%253A381%250Atc%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fofjxxt%253A18%253A179%250AJd%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fofjxxt%253A17%253A1%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fcivicrm%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fofjxxt%253A252%253A171%250Ax.Callbacks%252Fc%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fjquery_update%252Freplace%252Fjquery%252F1.10%252Fjquery.min.js%253Fv%253D1.10.2%253A4%253A26031%250Ax.Callbacks%252Fp.fireWith%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fjquery_update%252Freplace%252Fjquery%252F1.10%252Fjquery.min.js%253Fv%253D1.10.2%253A4%253A26840%250A.ready%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fjquery_update%252Freplace%252Fjquery%252F1.10%252Fjquery.min.js%253Fv%253D1.10.2%253A4%253A3303%250Aq%2540http%253A%252F%252Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%252Fsites%252Fall%252Fmodules%252Fjquery_update%252Freplace%252Fjquery%252F1.10%252Fjquery.min.js%253Fv%253D1.10.2%253A4%253A715%250A%0AS%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fofjxxt%3A6%3A417%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fofjxxt%3A35%3A320%0Ar%40http%3A%2F%2Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fofjxxt%3A7%3A320%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fofjxxt%3A34%3A399%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fofjxxt%3A35%3A63%0Ar%40http%3A%2F%2Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fofjxxt%3A7%3A320%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fofjxxt%3A34%3A399%0Acb%40http%3A%2F%2Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fofjxxt%3A38%3A135%0Atc%2Fd%40http%3A%2F%2Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fofjxxt%3A17%3A381%0Atc%40http%3A%2F%2Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fofjxxt%3A18%3A179%0AJd%40http%3A%2F%2Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fofjxxt%3A17%3A1%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fofjxxt%3A252%3A171%0Ax.Callbacks%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fjquery_update%2Freplace%2Fjquery%2F1.10%2Fjquery.min.js%3Fv%3D1.10.2%3A4%3A26031%0Ax.Callbacks%2Fp.fireWith%40http%3A%2F%2Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fjquery_update%2Freplace%2Fjquery%2F1.10%2Fjquery.min.js%3Fv%3D1.10.2%3A4%3A26840%0A.ready%40http%3A%2F%2Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fjquery_update%2Freplace%2Fjquery%2F1.10%2Fjquery.min.js%3Fv%3D1.10.2%3A4%3A3303%0Aq%40http%3A%2F%2Fstore.viewpointgallery.org%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fjquery_update%2Freplace%2Fjquery%2F1.10%2Fjquery.min.js%3Fv%3D1.10.2%3A4%3A715%0A

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! You are more likely to get a helpful answer if you could provide some more information.  In particular could you say which versions of CiviCRM and Drupal you updated from and to.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: You haven't provided the requested information, which is the versions of CiviCRM and Drupal. Eg CiviCRM version 4.7.12, Drupal 7.33. Also, if you could get someone to help with the English that might help. I'm going to edit it to what I think you are asking, but it's not very clear. Please correct if I get it wrong.

Comment: I am using Drupal 7.51 and civicrm 4.7.12. when I have tried to access CiviCRM Dashboard (<domain>/civicrm/dashboard?reset=1), its return blank civicrm Dashboard page. 

I have tried to find out issues using Mozila error console, I got following message : ts() not a function.